# Rest api Firebase unity

Tags: c#, firebase, api, rest, unity-game-engine

I want to get all the data (list of data) under a specific user Id.

my script only show the last data that been added to database under the specific user Id not all of it.

```
public void GetFromDatabase()
{
    // Get user ID from input field
    userId = user.UserId;

    // Get game ID
    gameId = GameIdText.text;

    //URL 
    string url = "https://cod-02-2023-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/" + userId + ".json";
    Debug.Log(url);

    // Use the RestClient to get the wave data from the database
    RestClient.Get<User>(url).Then(response =>
    {
        // Get the game data for the specified game ID
        userObj = response;

        // Update the UI with user data
        UpdateScore();
    });

}
```